# Getting client context token for other site collections

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin

Suppose I have two SPSites in SharePoint Online. My app is installed on an SPWeb in one of the site collections.

[image]
When running the app you get a context token for the site collection where the app is installed. Is is possible to get a client context for the other site collection, so my app can access data there too, given that the user running the app has sufficient permission? I don't want to use an AppOnly context, since this can't make changes to term sets in the term store.

Comment: If you're in SPO, you can give write access to tenant, and then app will be able to write to any list/web in any site collection, as long as the user has permissions.

Comment: I know, but that was not what I was asking for. I am wondering if it is possible to access the tenant object without the app only permission policy?

Comment: Granting an app permissions and app-only permissions are two different things.  You need to grant the app ability to read/write/manage certain objects, regardless of the user's permissions.

Comment: I guess this is possible but as mentioned by @wjervis you need to give app write permission on tenant as well as user should have that permission (as you are not using app-only policy)

Comment: Yes, the app has full control permissions over the tenancy, as does the user. So the question is, how would one instantiate a client context that can access the while tenancy without using the app only policy?

Comment: Simply instantiate a ClientContext object for the site you wish to work with.

Comment: @wjervis Can you do instantiate a new ClientContext from inside an app without having access to the user's password? (For example by using the current security token?)

Comment: I believe so.  The last time I used CSOM was when Microsoft was still trialing Auto-hosted apps, so it's been awhile.  But I created an app to upload documents to a library in a different site collection, and I don't recall having to do anything unique.  I did use REST though, that may have been why.